# How to predict a new value using simple linear regression log(y)=b0+b1*log(x)

Tags: regression, linear-regression, prediction, lm

How to predict a new given value of body using the ml2 model below, and interpret its output (new predicted output only, not model)

Using Animals dataset from MASS package to build a simple linear regression model

```
ml2<-lm(log(brain)~log(body),data=Animals)
```

*predict a new given body of 468*

```
pred_body<-data.frame(body=c(468))

predict(ml2,new, interval="confidence")

       fit      lwr      upr
1 5.604506 4.897498 6.311513
```

**But i am not so sure predicted y(brain) =5.6 or log(brain)=5.6?**

**How could we get the predicted value with the same scale as it original?**

Comment: Sorry @李哲源ZheyuanLi . I am new to StackOverflow, but now I know how to accept and vote the answers. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a formula `log(brain) ~ log(body)`, the response variable is `log(brain)`. So when you make prediction using `predict()`, you get fitted values and prediction interval for `log(brain)`.

To get corresponding results on original scale, do

```
exp(predict(ml2,new, interval="confidence"))
```